# Use google-map-react fitbounds useRef -> mapRef.current.fitBounds is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, zoom-sdk, fitbounds, google-map-react

I use [google-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react) and I want to have the correct zoom and center to the map.
To center the map I use the props center on GoogleMapReact component that I can calculate.
But for the zoom it is more complex.

I could see the use of fitBounds but that is not available on "google-map-react"

Is there a way to calculate the zoom so that it contains the markers that I have defined.
Or a function that does it by itself like fitbounds ?

Be careful not to confuse "[google-map-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-map-react)" (used here) with "react-google-map" (not used)

```
import GoogleMapReact from "google-map-react";
import {Place} from "@material-ui/icons";
import {useRef} from "react";


const Page = () => {

    const mapRef = useRef(null);

    const MarkerPlace = (props) => {
        return (
            <div>
                <Place fontSize={"large"}></Place>
                <p>{props.name}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const FitBounds = () => {
        let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        let lat = 38.103;
        let lng = -121.572;
        bounds.extend(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));

        console.log(mapRef.current) //o {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, _getMinZoom: ƒ, …}

        //The error occurs at the line below
        mapRef.current.fitBounds(bounds) //TypeError: mapRef.current.fitBounds is not a function
        //The error occurs at the line above
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <GoogleMapReact ref={mapRef} bootstrapURLKeys={{key: ""}} center={defaultCenter} defaultZoom={13}
                {view === "recherche" && currentSearchData.map((activity, index) => (
                    <MarkerPlace key={index} lat={activity.latitude} lng={activity.longitude} name={activity.name}/>
                 ))}
            </GoogleMapReact>
            <button onclick={FitBounds}>FitBounds</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Page;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fitBounds` does exist in *google-map-react*, but it's a separate utility function rather than a function on the instance. There are examples of how to use it in the [api](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/HEAD/API.md#fitbounds-func). According to the [source code](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/a783cd62767f824a6eb072e523c8d06ea660c7ee/src/lib/index.js), `fitBounds` is defined to take corner boundaries as the first parameter, and a height/width dictionary as the second:

```js
export function fitBounds({ nw, se, ne, sw }, { width, height }) {
```

and it returns a new object with `newBounds`, presumably to be destructured and used to set the new `center` and `zoom`.